# Hosting asp page on linux server

Tags: linux, asp-classic

Is it possible to host an asp page on a linux server ?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, YES, there are implementations of ASP which will run under Linux.

In practice, NO, your ASP application has probably been written for Windows and will use SQL server (which means you need a Windows box anyway to run that) and probably some COM classes which are unavailable.

But even if you COULD run it, the chances of introducing bugs by moving it to an alien platform is very high.

Also in my experience, the chances of an ASP app having bugs is very high to start with.

Answer (score 0):

checkout [ASP.NET mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET)

Answer (score 0):

how about [this](http://asp-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/running_asp_on_a_linux_server) ? or [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)?

Answer (score 0):

Years ago, I've heard of Chili!ASP. I don't know if that's still around anymore.